# How can one build a min-2-wise independent small sample space from min-3-wise permutations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, permutations, sampling

I have been studying a polynomial-size set of permutations from one of my lectures. The below image, taken from the lecture notes [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PrZCZOO9yL-Ls1k0wsgJXcHKVin9f0X_/view?usp=drivesdk), illustrates how to construct min-3-wise permutations.

[image: Min-3-wise Permutations Illustration]

My question is: How can one build a min-2-wise independent small sample space from min-3-wise permutations, and could you provide a proof for this construction?